# Google App Engine - Datastore java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entity is too big

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

When I try to save an entity, the Datastore throws the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entity is too big
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:53)
....
```

Comment: The datastore has a maximum limit to write an entity that is at most 1MB (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits), ideally to segregate in another table the information with volumes

Answer (score 2):

There's limitation to [Google Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits). The official recommendation is to split up your large entity into a logical [Entity group](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities#Python_Kinds_and_identifiers) with ancestors and their children defined.

Think of it like nested records. If you create an entity called "Employees", you can create children entities like "Performance" and "Profile". This way you don't need that employee's entire history and profile in one entity.

Basically, you can design your datastore structure to ensure each individual entity do not exceed 1MB in size.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, each unindexed String property can be [up to 1MB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/entity-property-reference), and total entity size 1MB. The "Limits" doc in the comment on OP was updated to use this value.

Entity groups can be a solution here.